# Loop through divs with class X to find correlation with divs Y

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to write a script that would let me to:

- loop through `.display-player-box` elements setting each `id` as variable,
- loop through `.removefromsquad` elements to find one which part of class attribute coresponds with previously found `.display-player-box` `id`,
- if the coresponding element is found i want to add a class `.selected` to this particular `.display-player-box` that matched.

Code I've written so far:

```
$(".display-player-box").each(function() {                     // start looping
    $selected = 0;                                             // set a variable to default
    $boxid = $(this).attr("id");                               // set id of element being looped as variable
    $(".removefromsquad").each(function() {                    // loop through another row of elements
        if ($(this).attr("class").slice(16, 17) == $boxid) {   // looking for part of it's class matching previously saved variable
            $selected = 1;                                     // if yes, update variable 
        };
    });
    if ($selected == 1) {                                      // if variable was updated...
        $(this).addClass("selected");                          // add class to .display-player-box
    } else {                                                   // if not...
        $(this).removeClass("selected");                       // make sure it's removed
    }
});
```

The problem is - it simply doesn't work, it wouldn't add the class when elements are matched. There are no errors in console tho. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".display-player-box").each(function() {
                    $selected = 0;
                    $boxid = $(this).attr("id");
                    $(".removefromsquad").each(function() { 
                        if ($(this).attr("class").slice(16, 17) == $boxid) {
                            $selected = 1;   
                        };
                    });
                    if ($selected == 1) {
                        $(this).addClass("selected");
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass("selected");
                    }
                });
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Team slots:</p>
<div class="removefromsquad">EMPTY SLOT</div>
<div class="removefromsquad">EMPTY SLOT</div>
<div class="removefromsquad 3">PLAYER #3</div>
<div class="removefromsquad 4">PLAYER #4</div>

<p>Players to fill slots:</p>
<div class="display-player-box" id="1">PICK PLAYER #1</div>
<div class="display-player-box" id="2">PICK PLAYER #2</div>
<div class="display-player-box" id="3">PICK PLAYER #3</div>
<div class="display-player-box" id="4">PICK PLAYER #4</div>
```

Comment: What's the question/error/issue?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @stephen.vakil I've updated question, didn't notice it was unclear at first sight

Comment: Use jQuery.  There is no reason to slice a class when you have [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/).

Comment: The code you posted works.  (What browser are you using).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post works, but it can be significantly shortened.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".removefromsquad").removeClass("selected");
  $(".display-player-box").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).prop("id");
    $(".removefromsquad." + id).addClass("selected");
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Team slots:</p>
<div class="removefromsquad">EMPTY SLOT</div>
<div class="removefromsquad">EMPTY SLOT</div>
<div class="removefromsquad 3">PLAYER #3</div>
<div class="removefromsquad 4">PLAYER #4</div>

<p>Players to fill slots:</p>
<div class="display-player-box" id="1">PICK PLAYER #1</div>
<div class="display-player-box" id="2">PICK PLAYER #2</div>
<div class="display-player-box" id="3">PICK PLAYER #3</div>
<div class="display-player-box" id="4">PICK PLAYER #4</div>
```

If I were to design this as a reusable component, I would have changed it to something like the following.  I hope the following really helps you graps how to create some really nice components.

[Highly Recommended Reading - Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-auto-selector").each(function() {
    var $container = $(this);
    var unselectSelector = $container.data("unselect");
    $container.find(unselectSelector).removeClass("selected");
    $container.find("[data-selector-target]").each(function() {
      var targetSelector = $(this).data("selector-target");
      $container.find(targetSelector).addClass("selected");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-auto-selector" data-unselect="removefromsquad">
  <p>Team slots:</p>
  <div class="removefromsquad">EMPTY SLOT</div>
  <div class="removefromsquad">EMPTY SLOT</div>
  <div class="removefromsquad select-3">PLAYER #3</div>
  <div class="removefromsquad select-4">PLAYER #4</div>

  <p>Players to fill slots:</p>
  <div class="display-player-box" data-selector-target=".select-1">PICK PLAYER #1</div>
  <div class="display-player-box" data-selector-target=".select-2">PICK PLAYER #2</div>
  <div class="display-player-box" data-selector-target=".select-3">PICK PLAYER #3</div>
  <div class="display-player-box" data-selector-target=".select-4">PICK PLAYER #4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately my internet connection stopped working yesterday for some reason. That's true, to my surprise, that the snippet i added seems to work just fine, maybe I have some typos in my real code, gotta check it. Thank you very much for the shortened version, definitely gave me an idea on how i may construct this type of scripts in a more effective way in the future!

Comment: I updated it with a very decoupled/reusable version.

Answer (score 1):

I personally couldn't get your code to run, as one commenter suggested, but you were very close, at any rate. Here is what I adapted from yours, adjusting slightly. Hopefully it helps.

```
$(".display-player-box").each(function() {
  var selected = false;
  var selfId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.removefromsquad').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(selfId)) {
      selected = true;
    }
  });

  if (selected) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
});
```